# drawing an image with RGB data in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have a text file containing RGB data for an image, how can I draw the image using this data in matlab?

data sample :

> Red  Green Blue
>    80    97   117
>    83   100   120
>    74    91   111
>    81    96   115
>    81    96   115
>    77    90   107
>    84    97   114
>    78    91   108
>    79    95   110
>    91   104   120
>    94   108   121
>    85    99   112

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [IMAGE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/image.html) command takes an MxNx3 matrix and displays it as an RGB image.  You can use [LOAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/load.html) and [RESHAPE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html) to get the data into the right format.  Finally, IMAGE wants either integers between 0 and 255 or doubles between 0 and 1.0, so you need to cast or rescale your numbers.  The following code snippet should show you how to put it all together.

```
x = load('rgbdata.txt'); % makes a 12x3 matrix
x = reshape(x, 2, 6, 3); % reshape pulls columnwise, assume 6x2 image
x = x/255; %scale the data to be between 0 and 1
image(x);
```